# Site errors out when trying to create a subtheme based on Classy

Tags: theming, 9

I'm creating a custom theme in Drupal 9 and am trying to use classy as my subtheme but get the following error:

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Drupal\Core\Theme\MissingThemeDependencyException: Base theme classy has not been installed. in Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeInitialization->getActiveThemeByName() (line 122 of core\lib\Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeInitialization.php).

Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeInitialization->initTheme('custom_theme') (Line: 406)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->initTheme(Object) (Line: 96)
Drupal\Core\Theme\ThemeManager->getActiveTheme() (Line: 214)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->init(NULL) (Line: 258)
Drupal\Core\Theme\Registry->getRuntime() (Line: 194)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 61)
Drupal\node\NodeViewBuilder->getBuildDefaults(Object, 'full') (Line: 157)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->viewMultiple(Array, 'full', NULL) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityViewBuilder->view(Object, 'full') (Line: 98)
Drupal\Core\Entity\Controller\EntityViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL) (Line: 66)
Drupal\node\Controller\NodeViewController->view(Object, 'full', NULL)
call_user_func_array(Array, Array) (Line: 123)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 573)
Drupal\Core\Render\Renderer->executeInRenderContext(Object, Object) (Line: 124)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->wrapControllerExecutionInRenderContext(Array, Array) (Line: 97)
Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\EarlyRenderingControllerWrapperSubscriber->Drupal\Core\EventSubscriber\{closure}() (Line: 158)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 80)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 57)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 106)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->pass(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 85)
Drupal\page_cache\StackMiddleware\PageCache->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 47)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 52)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 23)
Stack\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 705)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Below is my `theme.info.yml` info:

```
name: Custom Theme
type: theme
description: "This is a custom theme for the company"
version: "1.0.0"
core: 8.x
package: "Custom"
core_version_requirement: ^8 || ^9
base theme: classy

# libraries:
#   - custom_theme/bootstrap_cdn
#   - custom_theme/global-styling

regions:
  search: Hidden Search Bar
  branding_navigation: Branding & Main Navigation
  header: Header
  primary_menu: Primary menu
  secondary_menu: Secondary menu
  content: Content
  footer: Footer
```

Why is it saying that 'Base theme classy' isn't installed? I've never run into this issue before. Does it have something to do with Drupal 9? (This is my first time starting from scratch in D9)

I see that classy is in the core files so not sure why I'm getting this error?

Any help/suggestions?

**EDIT:** I'm using Acquia Dev Desktop if that makes any difference.

Comment: Here is a clue, D9's [bartik.info.yml](https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/9.0.x/core/themes/bartik/bartik.info.yml) doesn't set classy as base like in D8, yet it still uses the classy libraries hummmm.

Comment: I figured it had something to do with that but can't find an answer anywhere online. So I'm wondering if I just copy over all the classy css/template files over to my custom theme is the way to go?

Comment: Maybe related: https://www.drupal.org/node/3103178

Comment: Bartik isn't a subtheme anymore. It originally used Classy, that was later changed to Stable, and later changed to be a standalone theme. See https://www.drupal.org/node/3115223

Answer (score 0):

**The root of problem**: base theme changing after the theme has been installed.

**How to change base theme**:

- Enable another theme;
- Click on "Uninstall theme";
- Change base theme;
- Click on "Install and set default";